# How to prevent from right column collapsing (2 columns) - Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm completely new to Bootstrap and am trying to accomplish the following:

(Left column - larger)
Heading
Heading 2
Heading Image Heading Image
Heading
Address

(Right column - smaller)
Heading
Paragraph
List items

My question is how do I prevent the right column from collapsing below the left? I've tried setting a height, but of course that's temporary and it doesn't even work correctly. When I add more content, the right column immediately collapses below the left :(. I'm totally lost. I've been trying different things for hours. There's gotta be a simple fix that I'm not aware of?

This is what I have so far:

LEFT COLUMN:

```
  <div class='information'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-9'>
          <div id='schedule'>
            <h2>Schedule</h2>
              <h3>Sunday</h3>
              <div class='schedule-inner'>
                <div class='schedule-heading'>
                  <div class="media">
                  <h5 class="media-heading pull-left ">Location 1</h5>
                  <img class="media-object pull-left img-responsive" src="img/arrow.png" alt="..." />
                  <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Location 2</h5>
                  <img class="media-object pull-left img-responsive" src="img/arrow.png" alt="..." />
                 <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Location 3</h5>
                </div>
              </div>

                 <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>8:00am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      xxxxx<br>
                      xxxxx<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Name of location)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
```

RIGHT COLUMN:

```
<div class='pricing'>
          <div class='col-md-3'>
            <h3>Pricing</h3>
             <p>Lorem ispum</p>
            <ul>
              <li class='icon-sprite sprite-wifi'>Wifi internet</li>
              <li class='icon-sprite sprite-charger'>Charger</li>
              <li class='icon-sprite sprite-battery'>Charger</li>
           </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You should probably say what your intended outcome should be. Because it's not clear, do you want it not to collapse, do you want pricing to stay above schedule?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It collapses after adding more content? It should do it just when viewing the page in narrower browser.

You could try changing a bit the order of the divs and adding more grid options. If you wish the grid to always behave the same:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            <div class="information">
                Schedule information
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="pricing">
                Pricing information
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I would recommend leaving out atleast the col-xs- classes because with mobile view it gets really tight with both columns (for example in 320px viewport) and it's better to let it go below the other.

Here's little more about the grid options: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 1):

Change right columns class to `col-xs-3` and left content column class to `col-xs-9` and also make sure that the column the right column is sibling to left content column `col-md-9` in `row`.

```
<div class='pricing'>
      <div class='col-xs-3'>
        <h3>Pricing</h3>
         <p>Lorem ispum</p>
        <ul>
          <li class='icon-sprite sprite-wifi'>Wifi internet</li>
          <li class='icon-sprite sprite-charger'>Charger</li>
          <li class='icon-sprite sprite-battery'>Charger</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```